# Data structure for movie-theatre two way searching capability

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I am trying to design a online Movie ticket booking system where a user can search a movie/theater in a given city and then book a movie. Suppose he searched for a movie, I need to return that movie with all theaters along with the show timings for that movie. Similarly, if he searches for a theater, I need to return that theater with all movies in that theater along with show timings. 
I have no way to figure out if it's a movie or theater that user is searching. 
Which data structure should I use for efficient search? Here is what I thought of but it seems to be a brute force approach.
Here is my class (partial structure)

```
public class Theater {
  String theaterName;
  ArrayList<Movies> movies;
}
```

Suppose I store theaters as arraylist, I would end up parsing these theaters and making string comparisons with theater name and subsequently with movie names.

**Edit**: To avoid confusion, Issue is not how/where to persist data but which data structure to use to load that data in so that I can make efficient search operation around it

Comment: database is for storing data. I need to know which data structure should i use to initialize them for efficient search operation

Comment: @RaviChaudhary, look at hash-based data structures like `HashMap`, `HashSet` - they will give you `O(1)`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko : Using `HashMap` or `HashSet` would mean my key would either be movie or theater. Or are you suggesting `HashMap<String,String` to identify what user is trying to search with key being user string and value being type(movie/theater). for eg: key-pair being {deadpool, movie}, {inox,theater}

Comment: @RaviChaudhary, every `Theater` has a `Map<Integer, Movie>` (the movie id to a movie), you iterate over all  `Theater` and look up movies by the id

Comment: Once you consider using more than 1 data structure, the problem becomes fairly simple.

Comment: @Dukeling : Can you please elaborate yourself

Comment: `but which data structure to use to load that data in so that I can make efficient search operation around it` Is there a particular reason you want to do the searching in memory, rather than in the database? Databases are **made** for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* load the data into memory at startup, and have two hash maps: one that that is `HashMap<TheaterId, ArrayList<MovieId>>`, and the other being `HashMap<MovieId, ArrayList<TheaterId>>`. That way you could look things up either way. The problem with this approach is that you either have to periodically check the database for updates, or somehow have the database notify you when updates occur so that you can update your data structures. But then you have to worry about concurrency (updating the data while users are querying it), and things get messy in a hurry.

That's what databases are for. They already know how to handle concurrent updates and queries, and if you set up your indexes correctly, you can search by movie, or by theater. If you're using a dedicated database server, the database will likely keep much of the index and the data cached in memory, so searches are likely to be very fast.

You have a lot to learn if you think that "database is for storing data." Database is for storing, transforming, manipulating, and retrieving data. And probably a few more things, as well.

Comment: I was planning to use database for city based filtering only. All theaters-movies could be fetched in one single request for a particular city. Problem i was trying to avoid was maintaining two hashmaps with similar data. Looks like it would be better to do all the filtering on database side only